# react-i18next api t() not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

My project have an error that "t is not a function".
And I console.log(t), 
it's undefined
There are my code

i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';


i18n
  .use(XHR)
  // .use(LanguageDetector) 
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'tw', 
    ns: ['common'],
    defaultNS: 'common', 
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false 
    },
    backend: {
      "loadPath": "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

index.js

```
....
import './i18n';

const Index = (props)=>(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
  </Provider>      
);

ReactDOM.render(<Index/>,document.querySelector("#container"));
```

components

```
.
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
.
.
class Landpage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        const { t } = this.props; // t undefined

.
.
.
```

please help me resolve this question and tell me why it's happend

Comment: How is Landpage used?

Comment: export default translate()(Landpage);
module.exports = Landpage;

Comment: When you render the Landpage component, did you pass a property called `t` to it?

Comment: thanks it's solved.. I export it two times